# Value in property from WCF service is getting System.ArgumentNullException saying it is null, when it isn't

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, argumentnullexception

I have a issue with a view being populated from a WCF service into a partial view. Everything works just fine and the model contains the data necessary, but somehow it keeps getting this error. I can clearly see the value for the ProduktDto so it isn't null at all, but still says it is.

Have heard that the error could be in the connectionString so I include it here:

```
 <add name="SpelDatabasContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/SpelDatabas.csdl|res://*/SpelDatabas.ssdl|res://*/SpelDatabas.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=SpelAffarenDatabas;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Havent found the answer for this after serious googling.
Here is the code for the view:

```
@model List<SpelAffarWCF.ProduktDto>
<table class="table table-responsive">
<tr>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th>Namn</th>
  <th>Beskrivning</th>
  <th>Utgivningsår</th>
  <th>MP</th>
  <th>SP</th>
  <th>Pris</th>
  <th>Utgivare</th>
  <th>Konsoler</th>
  <th>Genres</th>
  <th>Aktiv order antal</th>
</tr>
@foreach (var spel in Model)
{
  <tr>
     <td title="Spelets Id">@spel.Id</td>
     <td title="Spelets jävla namn">@spel.Namn</td>
     <td title="@spel.Beskrivning">För musen över mig..</td>
     <td title="När det släpptes">@spel.Utgivningsår</td>
     <td title="Multipläjer">@Html.CheckBox("checkboxMP", spel.Multiplayer)</td>
     <td title="Singlpläjer">@Html.CheckBox("checkboxSP", spel.Singleplayer)</td>
     <td title="Spelet kostar faktiskt såhär mycket">@spel.Pris</td>
     <td title="Id: @spel.Utgivare.Id, Spel: @spel.Utgivare.Produkter.Count()">@Html.ActionLink(spel.Utgivare.Namn, "EditPublisher", new { id = spel.Utgivare.Id })</td>
     @if (spel.Konsoler.Count() > 0)
     {
        <td>
           @foreach (var konsol in spel.Konsoler)
           {
              <p class="cellEntity">@konsol.Namn</p>
           }
        </td>
     }
     else
     {
        <td>Ingen.</td>
     }
     @if (spel.Genres.Count() > 0)
     {
        <td>
           @foreach (var genres in spel.Genres)
           {
              <p class="cellEntity">@genres.Namn</p>
           }
        </td>
     }
     else
     {
        <td>Ingen genre.</td>
     }
     @if (spel.SpelPerOrders.Count() > 0)
     {
        <td>
           @foreach (var spelOrder in spel.SpelPerOrders)
           {
              <p class="cellEntity">Id: @spelOrder.OrderId, @spelOrder.Antal st</p>
           }
        </td>
     }
     else
     {
        <td>Finns inte i någon order.</td>
     }
     <td>
        <input type="button" value="Lägg till i kundvagn" onclick="AddToCart(@spel.Id)" />
     </td>
    </tr>
  }
  </table>
```

Comment: If the `Model` is not null, it could be 1. A null object inside the `Model` collection, or 2. one of the `spel` objects in the collection has a null `Konsoler` property.

Comment: the crash occurs always at @spel.Pris, or if i remove it, the corresponding place to the next property, so it always crashes on the 7th property... when debuging I can see that all the properties is not null....

Comment: That's certainly strange... `spel.Utgivare` and `spel.Utgivare.Produkter` are both non-null?

Comment: Yes, nothing in the Model contains null at all.

Comment: ParaeterName: source is the one that is faulting

Comment: That's probably the `spel.Utgivare.Produkter.Count()` or `spel.Konsoler.Count()` call. The parameter of the [Linq `Count` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535181%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is named `source`.

Comment: OMG dude that's it! Countless of hours of debugging and searching desperately for a solution, having my teacher helping my without prevail...fantastic! Thank you so much!

Comment: Heyyyy! You're welcome :) I've added an answer so I can collect my sweet, sweet Stackoverflow points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates it's either the `spel.Utgivare.Produkter.Count()` or `spel.Konsoler.Count()` call; the parameter of the Linq `Count` extension method is named `source`.